# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

Can anyone help me, I have a problem with the dataset

Can anyone help me, I'm having a problem with running the dataset.

It's returning an error saying it didn't expect a DataFrame in the DataSet function

```
N_train = int(0.8*len(df))
train_ds,test_ds = train_test_split(adjusted_df, train_size = N_train)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(18,8))

axes[0].hist(train_ds['label'].iloc[:].values.reshape(-1),  bins=nClasses)
axes[0].set_title('Histograma - Saída desejada - Treinamento');
axes[1].hist(test_ds['label'].values.reshape(-1), bins= nClasses)
axes[1].set_title('Histograma - Saída desejada - Teste');

import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

batch_size = 27

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),
                              ])

train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(test_ds, download=False, train=True, transform=transform)
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True)

#train_dataset = train_ds #torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(train_ds)
#train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)

#test_dataset = test_ds #TensorDataset(test_ds)
#test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)

test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(test_ds, download=False, train=False, transform=transform)
test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `datasets.MNIST` is the path to the data directory instead of the dataframe. It looks like you already have your data in `adjusted_df`; then you don't need to call `datasets.MNIST`.

https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.MNIST